# Searching and deleting rows in Custom ListView

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, adapter

I'm trying to create a ListView for a Friends list. It has a search functiton in which tthe user can search for a particular freind and then delete them as a friend, message them and so forth.

However, I'm having trouble removing them. I don't think I understand the positioning, or finding out the correct position on where the users freind is in the list.

I want to make sure that in all cases, the user is removed from the correct position. For instance, if the user uses the search function and only one user is returned. Then I don't want the user to be removed at position 0 (one user), I want it to be removed at the correct position so that when the user goes back to the full list. Position 0 in the list isn't accidentaly removed.

Could someone review the code? and show a slight indication as to where I am going wrong with this?

[image]
[image]

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        res = getResources();
        searchField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        //button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFriendList);
        lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        //button.setFocusable(false);
        list = new ArrayList<Friend>();

        nameBlock = res.getStringArray(R.array.names);
        descBlock = res.getStringArray(R.array.descriptions);

        names = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < nameBlock.length; i++) {
            names.add((String)nameBlock[i]);
        }
        descr = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < descBlock.length; i++) {
            descr.add((String)descBlock[i]);
        }
        images = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < imageBlock.length; i++) {
            images.add((Integer)imageBlock[i]);
        }
        //imageBlock = res.getIntArray(R.array.images);

        int size = nameBlock.length;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < size; i++) {
            Log.d("FREINDADD", "Freind Added" + i);
            list.add(new Friend(i, names.get(i), descr.get(i), images.get(i)));
            //friendList2.add(new Friend(i, names.get(i), descr.get(i), images.get(i)));
        }
        Log.i("Application", "Application started succesfully...");

        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this);


        setListAdapter(adapter);
        Log.i("VIRTU", "Count" + adapter.getCount());
        //adapter.getCount();


        searchField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {
            @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
            @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
            @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                list.clear();
                textlength = searchField.getText().length();

                for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
                {
                    if (textlength <= names.get(i).length())
                    {
                        if(names.get(i).toLowerCase().contains(searchField.getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim())) {
                            Log.i("VirtuFriendList", "List recyling in process... ");
                            list.add(new Friend(i, names.get(i), descr.get(i), images.get(i)));

                        }
                      }
                }
                AppendList(list);

                }
        });


    }
    public void AppendList(ArrayList<Friend> list) {
        setListAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this));
    } 

    class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;
        public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
            this.context = context;

        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return list.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return list.size();
        }
        class ViewHolder {
            TextView userName;
            TextView userDesc;
            ImageView userImage;
            Button userButton;


            ViewHolder(View view) {
                userImage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
                userName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
                userDesc = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.mutualTitle);
                userButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn);
            }
        }
        ViewHolder holder;
        View row;
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                row = convertView;

                if(row == null) 
                {
                    // If it is visible to the user, deploy the row(s) - allocated in local memory
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_list_item, parent, false);
                    holder = new ViewHolder(row);
                    row.setTag(holder);
                    Log.d("VIRTU", "Row deployed...");
                }
                else 
                {
                    // Recycle the row if it is not visible to to the user - store in local memory
                    holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
                    Log.d("VIRTU", "Row recycled...");
                }
                Friend temp = list.get(position);

                // Set the resources for each component in the list
                holder.userImage.setImageResource(temp.getImage());
                holder.userName.setText(temp.getName());
                holder.userDesc.setText(temp.getDesc());

                ((Button)row.findViewById(R.id.btn)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        PopupMenu pop = new PopupMenu(getApplicationContext(), v);
                        MenuInflater inflater = pop.getMenuInflater();

                        inflater.inflate(R.menu.firned_popup_action,pop.getMenu());
                        pop.show();
                        pop.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                                int choice = item.getItemId();

                                switch(choice) {
                                case R.id.message:
                                    break;

                                case R.id.unfollow:
                                        break;
                                case R.id.unfriend:
                                    int position = (Integer)row.getTag();
                                    list.remove(position);
                                    names.remove(position);
                                    images.remove(position);
                                    descr.remove(position);
                                    adapter = new CustomAdapter(context);
                                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    break;

                                case R.id.cancel:
                                }

                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

            return row;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: if you want to delete some users you need to keep them somewhere,  where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think as your structure stands, you will continue to have this problem. My suggestion would be to assign a FriendID (or something similar) to each friend, and when you are building your list, instead of just passing userImage, userName, userDesc and userButton, pass along friendID as well.

For example, I have five friends, and here is their information:

```
userImage   userName   userDesc   userButton   friendID
x           Jordyn     x          x            0
x           Sam        x          x            1
x           Connor     x          x            2
x           Paul       x          x            3
x           Raphael    x          x            4
```

But my search for (pretending you can search by one letter) those with 'o' in their name returns,

```
userImage   userName   userDesc   userButton   friendID
x           Jordyn     x          x            0
x           Connor     x          x            2
```

That way, when you delete the 1th row, it actually removes friendID = 2 from your friend list instead of the 1th row from your original friend list, which would've been Sam, which was not your intention.

Hope that helps!

EDIT:

1: add a hidden TextView to your rows called FriendID in your layout file (let me know if you need help with that).

Now, ViewHolder will look like this:

```
class ViewHolder {
            TextView userName;
            TextView userDesc;
            ImageView userImage;
            Button userButton;
            TextView friendID;

            ViewHolder(View view) {
                userImage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
                userName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
                userDesc = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.mutualTitle);
                userButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn);
                friendID = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.friendID);
            }
        }
```

2: add an arraylist for the friendIDs:

```
...
descr = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < descBlock.length; i++) {
            descr.add((String)descBlock[i]);
        }
        images = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < imageBlock.length; i++) {
            images.add((Integer)imageBlock[i]);
        }
        friendIDs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < friendIDsBlock.length; i++) {
            images.add((Integer)friendIdsBlock[i]);
        }
...
```

3: searchField.addTextChangedListener will now look like:

```
int size = nameBlock.length;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < size; i++) {
            Log.d("FREINDADD", "Freind Added" + i);
            list.add(new Friend(i, names.get(i), descr.get(i), images.get(i)));
            //friendList2.add(new Friend(i, names.get(i), descr.get(i), images.get(i), friendIds.get(i)));
        }
        Log.i("Application", "Application started succesfully...");
```

4: Now, when you unfriend someone, make sure to get the FriendID at the selected row as opposed to the row index. Then, remove the friend from the search list with the given FriendID as well as the friend from the general friend list with the given FriendID.

You'll have to forgive me, I don't have an IDE in front of me at the moment but I think that about covers it!

Comment: S, So would I just hold a userId in the Friend class. How would I go about retrieving this data from the row that the user is on?

Comment: @user3739821 just made an edit, let me know what works/makes sense/doesn't work/doesn't make sense!